# How can I manage overlapping DropDownBox drawers?

Tags: c#, winforms

Most of my dropdown boxes use the `SuggestAppend` property, meaning when you start typing in the box, it will make a shortlist of the items that match your case. However, if I do this after opening the drawer, this happens:

[image]

I have tried using this method, but it closes both instead of just one:

```
private void cmbLoc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbLoc.Text != "")
    {
        cmbLoc.DroppedDown = false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to have it so that when I type something into the text box, the original dropdown will disappear, and the `SuggestAppend` draw will appear. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked if I used `KeyDown`. Try and tell if that helps

```
    private void cmbLoc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        comboBox.DroppedDown = false;
    }
```